# React Router does not clear state when navigating to another URL with the same route but a different dynamic segment

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router 6.16.0 to create a single page application. The application has a route like `/page/:pageId`. This works fine.

When this page is opened it contains links to other pages with different `pageId` values, but still under the same route. So, for example, if I opened the URL `/page/1`, there could be links there to, say, `/page/2` and `/page/3`. Clicking on these links navigates to those other pages which also works fine.

The `/page/:pageId` page also has some other interactive elements. I tested this with theexample of a counter:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

<div>
    Counter: {counter}
    <button type="button" onClick={()=>setCounter(counter+1)}>Klik me</button>
</div>
```

Clicking the button increases the counter, as expected.

However, what surprised me was that navigating to a different pageId via the above mentioned links does *not* reset the counter. Only if you navigate to a completely different route and then back again will the counter get reset.

On one hand this makes sense because from React's point of view it's still the same component being rendered. On the other hand, from a user's point of view they've navigated to a different page and it should be reset.

I could work this into the component itself (that it would detect the change of ID and reset itself) but it feels like this should be handled by React Router instead. Unfortunately I cannot find a setting that would control this behavior. Is there such a setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this behavior, you can use react `key`s. If you had multiple `<Route>`s with ids that are known up front, you could put the key right where you render the route:

```
<Route path="/page/1" element={<Page key={1}/>} />
<Route path="/page/2" element={<Page key={2}/>} />
```

In your case though where you're using a route parameter, you won't know the key at the time you render the route. So you'll need to handle it in the page component. I suggest splitting the page component into an inner and outer component. The outer component is just in charge of remounting the the inner component.

```
<Route path="/page/:pageId" element={<Page/>} />
//...

const Page = () => {
  const { pageId } = useParams();
  return <InnerComponent key={pageId}/>
}

const InnerComponent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return <div>
    Counter: {counter}
    <button type="button" onClick={()=>setCounter(counter+1)}>Klik me</button>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yes, that would work. But it's really a workaround. Is there indeed no way to make React router do this by itself? It feels like this should be standard/default functionality.

Comment: Correct, there is no way to make react router do this by itself. The `<Routes>` component looks through its children, evaluates their paths against the current location, and then outputs the corresponding element. When react does reconciliation, it just sees that element, not the logic that went into choosing it. Absent a key, the react will compare the element types, see that the type has not changed, and thus update the instance instead of unmounting. A key can be provided to override this behavior. https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#resetting-state-with-a-key

Comment: In principal, the `<Routes>` component could have been built differently, so that instead of outputting 1 element, it outputs a bunch of nulls for inactive routes and 1 element for the active route. And then when the route changes, a null would become an element, and an element become a null, which could then cause mounting/unmounting. But they didn't design it that way. I don't know the history of why they implemented it the way they did.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I would think that the easiest way would be for React router to add a random `key` whenever navigation happens. But it doesn't do it, so it doesn't matter. No problem, I can add it myself.

Comment: Using a React key to force remount the routed component ***is*** a workaround. A "more correct" method could be to use a `useEffect` hook in the routed component to reset the `count` state when the path parameter changes. See the marked duplicate that covers both these use cases/solutions.

Comment: While that does work, I disagree that that's a "more correct" approach. It does give you the ability to do more targetted resets if you want, say, some states to reset and others to not. But if your goal is to do a complete reset (reset all states, blur the focused element if any, clear all uncontrolled inputs, etc), then changing the key is the standard way to tell react to mount a new instance when the element type alone is not enough.